# Access to path is denied on startup

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight 5.0 application that crashes when visiting the application using Windows 8 and Internet Explorer. It works just fine with any other combination: Windows 7 and IE, Windows 7 and Chrome or Firefox, and Windows 8 with Chrome or Firefox.

The application crashes very early in the startup process. Here is the message and stack trace:

**Message:** Access to the path 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\InBrowser\Profiles' is denied.

**Stack Trace**

```
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.UnsafeCreateDirectory(String path)
   at System.Windows.Application.StartMulticoreJit()
   at System.Windows.Application.Application_Starting(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

The stack trace makes it look like on startup Silverlight is trying to create a directory on the user's computer but is failing due to a permission issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, only I haven't been able to duplicate it myself in Windows 8 and IE10 as you have.  For some reason it works for me but I've had some of these error reports from customers recently.

As an experiment, I've just added `IE=8` to the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag on the page that holds the Silverlight app so it's now as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true,IE=8" />
```

This solves a [refresh bug with IE10](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/db07a063-35e2-4385-bf91-fe9324ee3d31/silverlight-app-disappears-on-page-refresh-in-ie10) and I'm hoping it'll also solve this error.  I'll just have to wait and see if anymore error reports come in.  Or maybe you can let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but for others searching out there for a solution:
The solution that worked for me was to un-check a box in internet explorer options:

Internet options -> Security -> Local intranet -> Enable Protected Mode